# How do I monitor symlinked modules with Nodemon?

Tags: node.js, npm, symlink, nodemon

I’m developing a module in Node.js which I’ve npm-linked into another projects node_modules folder. I’d like to restart this other projects server upon file changes in my module. Nodemon ignores node_modules by default, but I assumed I could override this using **nodemon --watch node_modules/my_module** – but can’t get it to work. If I temporarily remove node_modules from Nodemons lib/config/defaults.js it works, which probably confirms that the problem has to do with overriding default behavior.

Comment: Running into this myself. I thought of using forever.js, but it looks like that library doesn't actually support sending log output to stdout (which is a dealbreaker in my opinion).

Comment: ...aaaand I found the solution. I suppose I should have actually tried this before.

Answer (score 11):

Using `nodemon` 1.2.1, I'm able to do the following to get watches working with an npm link:

```
$ nodemon --watch . --watch $(realpath node_modules/my_module)
```

Basically...you have to watch the directory you're in (your project directory), and then specify a watch to the symlink itself. `nodemon` by default ignores `node_modules`, so explicitly specifying the watch fixes this. You may try updating your version of `nodemon` if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore, see [this issue](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/794);

Comment: @Tamlyn Hey - feel free to edit my answer to include a new fix, if it exists. If it's a good answer, I can make this community wiki and leave it open for edits.

Comment: This worked for me just now after I ran `brew install coreutils` (macOS). Otherwise `realpath` command was not found. It's a good idea to run `realpath node_modules/my_module` separately to ensure it returns something meaningful and only then call `nodemon ...`.

Comment: Using this solution I created a small wrapper that will automatically watch all linked modules. Just `npm install -g linkemon`, and then just use the `linkemon` command in place of `nodemon`.